# Assign value to cell with button press in google sheet modalDialog

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with client data.
I use the phone number as a unique ID. I know it's not ideal, I'll change it later, for now it's fine.

On an other sheet, `Column B` is the user name, `Column C` is phone number, with data validation range on the client data sheet.

Whenever there is a new entry in `Column B`, the function `selectClient(clientName)` is called. `clientName` is an array with the names and phone numbers that match the entered name.

It displays a popup HTML, with buttons for each row of the array.

I need to set the value of the `Column C` in the row where the new entry is made, with the phone number in the HTML button that is pressed.

What is the simplest way?

```
function selectClient(clientName){
  var phoneRows = lookUpClientPhone(clientName);
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test');
  t.data = phoneRows;
  html = t.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Egyező nevek');
}

 function lookUpClientPhone(clientName){
  var ugyfelRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('Ügyfél!B2:D');
  var ugyfelRangeSize = realRangeHeight(ugyfelRange);
  ugyfelRangeSize++;
  ugyfelRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('Ügyfél!B2:D'+ ugyfelRangeSize);
  var clientPhone = ugyfelRange.getValues();
  clientPhone = clientPhone.filter(function(row){
    return removeAccents(row[0]).toLowerCase() === removeAccents(clientName).toLowerCase()});
  return clientPhone;
}
```

The HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><button id="button<?i?>" type="submit" onClick="" value="<? data[i][2] ?>"><?= data[i]?></button></td>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you calling `selectClient(clientName)`? An on edit trigger?

Comment: since you give `data` to the html, you can simply supply the original index before you call `filter` - one way is to use map() first: `clientPhone = ugyfelRange.getValues().map(function (row, index) { row.unshift(index); return row; }).filter(....`

Comment: @Diego Yes, in the `onEdit()` function if the `activeRange()` is in the relevant column, I call the `selectClient(clientName)` function where `clientName` is `activeRange.getValue()`

Comment: @tehhowch I stil don't understand how to connect back the button click to the google script part. I must be missing something very trivial knowledge. Please help fill the holes.

Comment: @PeterVarga we can't possibly know what to suggest you do in your client code, because you didnt post any of it.

Comment: @tehhowch fair point! Thanks for reminding. I edited it in. edit: I knew I forgot something, when I posted to question...

Comment: @PeterVarga I don't see any JavaScript functions in your client side code, just the template initialization. Try writing one - in particular, write a function that will be registered as an `onclick` event handler for your button. You should review the `HtmlService` guide on client-server communication before you write it.